# Create horizon chart on R using ggplot2: show percentage change

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am a beginner at this and am really lost about it.

I would like to create a horizon chart that shows the percentage change in sales for the different towns using ggplot2 and R. Would anyone guide me in the approach I can take to create the chart?

The data that I have looks like this.
[image]

This is the type of chart I would like to do. 
(source: https://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/2017/11/friday-fun-li-horizon-charts.html) 
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help given!

Edit: here's a sample code of the data:

```
x <- data.frame(
  "town" =c('sad','sad','sad','sad','happy','happy','happy','happy'),
  "month"=c("2017-01","2017-02","2017-03","2017-04","2017-01","2017-02","2017-03","2017-04"),
  "median_sales" = c(336500,355000,375000,395000,359000,361500,36000,375000),
  "percentage_change" = c(NA,5.4977712,5.6338028,5.3333333,NA,0.6963788,-0.4149378,  4.1666667
))

x <-
  x %>%
  mutate(month = floor_date(as_date(as.yearmon(month)), "month"))
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be helpful to give an example that will result in a reasonable plot, and to provide your example data as data rather than an image.

If you google 'horizon plot' the first answer should give you what you need.

Here is a simple example based on the data you gave:

```
library(latticeExtra)

sales.ts <- ts(matrix(sales$median_sales, ncol=2), names = c("sad", "happy"),
               start = c(2017, 1), frequency = 365)

horizonplot(sales.ts)
```

I think this is correctly presenting your results, but again hard to tell as you haven't given a realistic dataset.

UPDATE: based on the data provided, this is the answer. Again, as you've only provided one time point a horizonplot is probably not what you want. They are designed to plot time series.

```
x.ts <- ts(matrix(x$median_sales, ncol=2), names = c("sad", "happy"),
                  start = c(2015, 1), frequency = 12)

horizonplot(x.ts)
```

Comment: hey peter! thanks so much for the reply. I don't know how i can attach the dataset, but you may access the real dataset here: https://data.gov.sg/dataset/resale-flat-prices?resource_id=42ff9cfe-abe5-4b54-beda-c88f9bb438ee thanks again!

Comment: It seems you have not fully thought through your problem, as the data you referred me to contains multiple entries per month and town. Do you want to sum all of the resale values across all units in the town for each month? Either make your example download the data from the website, or just paste some representative data into your code example.

Comment: hi peter, thanks again for the reply. I have edited the question with a sample code. Please let me know if that will be helpful!